# как обойти декартово объединение?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть  3 таблицы, которые содержат:

1. id
2. значение время (li.create_date)
3. тип подписки (o.dtype)

Запрос

```
    select distinct us.id, us.status, li.create_date purchase_date, o.dtype
    from  user_subscription us
    inner join product p on us.subscription = p.id
    inner join user_subscription_history ush on ush.user_subscription = us.id
    inner join offer o on o.id = ush.offer
    inner join line_item li on us.id = li.user_subscription
    where us.id = 38996954`
```

id содержит два типа подписки, каждый тип подписки имеет свое временное значение. В результате выборки я получаю по два временных значения на каждый тип подписки. Как выбрать конкретное временное значение для конкретного типа подписки?
Текущий результат:

```
   38996954;"Cancelled";"2016-06-23  03:29:01.447";"UnlimitedSubscriptionOffer"
   38996954;"Cancelled";"2016-06-23 03:28:33.384";"GiftOffer"
   38996954;"Cancelled";"2016-06-23 03:28:33.384";"UnlimitedSubscriptionOffer"
   38996954;"Cancelled";"2016-06-23 03:29:01.447";"GiftOffer"
```

Comment: Никак. У вас таблицы line_item и user_subscription_history никак не связаны между собой. Вы получаете некое время из line_item, но при этом тип подписки вы почему то получаете не на основе той записи в которой лежит время, а на основе некой истории подписок которая судя по запросу с line_item не имеет ничего общего. Сказать больше не зная полную структуру ваших _пяти_ таблиц и логики связей между ними невозможно

Comment: спасибо, понял, попробую добавить user_subscription_history таблицу сюда. В любом случае на основании выше упомянутых данных получить желаемое не получится, а значит надо копать в другую сторону.